# Is a nowhere locally compact, $\sigma$-compact space necessarily countable?

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to solve [another question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4399420/a-sigma-compact-separable-zero-dimensional-metric-space-has-property-stronger), and it'd help me if the following result holds:

> A nowhere locally compact, $\sigma$-compact separable metric space is countable.

Here nowhere locally compact means that no point has compact neighbourhood.

Further motivation for this question is that $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ are nowhere locally compact, the latter isn't $\sigma$-compact.

Comment: Can you give an example of such space?

Comment: If my hypothesis is true, then the only such spaces are rational numbers or empty space, because it can't have isolated points. If I were to find some other such space, then it would be a counter-example.

Comment: So you can assume that there is an uncountable set with no compact neighborhood, yet covered by countable collection of compact sets.

Comment: What about $\mathbb{Q}\times [0,1]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb{Q}\times [0,1]$ is a counterexample. It is an uncountable separable metric space (a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$). It is clearly $\sigma$-compact since it is $\bigcup_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} \{ q\}\times [0,1]$. But in every neighborhood there are sequences that don't have an accumulation point, namely sequences of the form $(q_n, r)_{n}$, where $r \in [0,1]$ is fixed and the $q_n$ converge to an irrational.

Comment: Good example. If we take $\mathbb{Q}\times C$ where $C$ is the Cantor set instead then it's even zero-dimensional.